# From a pandas DataFrame, how can I create copy-and-pasteable text that will re-create the same DataFrame, including the index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

#### Motivation:

I have a CSV with some data, which is then loaded into a pandas DataFrame `raw_data`. While unit testing I want to do some aggregation or other process on `raw_data`, to create a new DataFrame, `df`, and then confirm that the results (i.e. `df`) are what I expect.

This means I need to specify, in the unit test, what the results should look like, including the index. Since I have to do this a lot, it's tedious to manually create the exemplars to test against. What I want to do is, in an interactive session, construct the correct result dataframe and then convert it into something I can paste into my test module.

In other words, I want some function `f` with inverse function `F`, such that `f(df)` is something I can copy and paste, and `F(f(df)) == df`

#### Example

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'foo': [1, 2, 3],
    'bar': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'baz': ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    'qux': ['z', 'y', 'x']
}).set_index(['baz', 'qux'])
```

What I want to do is to take `df`, get something I can copy and paste into my test module, and create an exact copy of `df`.

I have tried `to_dict` and `to_json`, but for all values of `orient` either there's an exception or the index is not recreated correctly (often, the *names* of the index are left out).

Here's code to confirm this:

##### `to_dict`

```py
orientations = ['dict', 'split', 'series', 'records', 'list', 'index']

print('\t'.join(['orient', 'eqval', 'valexc', 'eqidx', 'idxexc']))

for orient in orientations:
    try:
        # Convert df to a dict, which I can __repr__ and then copy and paste
        serialized_df = df.to_dict(orient=orient)
        # Then, in theory I should be able to recreate the original df from
        # the dictionary object
        ser_de_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(serialized_df, orient=orient)
        
        equal_values = df.equals(ser_de_df)
        values_exception = False
    except:
        equal_values = False
        values_exception = True
        
    try:
        equal_index = df.index.equals(ser_de_df.index) and df.index.names == ser_de_df.index.names
        index_exception = False
    except:
        equal_index = False
        index_exception = True
        
    print('\t'.join(map(str, [orient, equal_values, values_exception, equal_index, index_exception])))
```

This produces:

```
orient  eqval   valexc  eqidx   idxexc
dict    False   True    False   False
split   False   True    False   False
series  False   True    False   False
records False   True    False   False
list    False   True    False   False
index   True    False   False   False
```

So, `orient='index'` creates an equal-value DataFrame, but the index loses the names.

##### JSON

Here's code to confirm no value of `orient` works for JSON:

```py
orientations = {'split', 'records', 'index', 'columns', 'values', 'table'}

print('\t'.join(['orient', 'eqval', 'valexc', 'eqidx', 'idxexc']))

for orient in orientations:
    try:
        # Convert to JSON, which I could just copy and paste as a string
        serialized_df = df.to_json(orient=orient)
        # Load back into a DataFrame
        ser_de_df = pd.read_json(serialized_df, orient=orient)
        
        equal_values = df.equals(ser_de_df)
        values_exception = False
    except:
        equal_values = False
        values_exception = True
        
    try:
        equal_index = df.index.equals(ser_de_df.index) and df.index.names == ser_de_df.index.names
        index_exception = False
    except:
        equal_index = False
        index_exception = True
        
    print('\t'.join(map(str, [orient, equal_values, values_exception, equal_index, index_exception])))
```

Produces:

```
orient  eqval   valexc  eqidx   idxexc
columns False   False   False   False
table   True    False   True    False
index   False   False   False   False
split   False   True    False   False
records False   False   False   False
values  False   False   False   False
```

So `table` creates equal values, but not equal index.

I could, of course, manually add code to set the index names correctly again, but it seems odd that there would not be a way to consistently serialize a DataFrame including the complete index (other than to a file like with `to_pickle`, etc.).

Is there a better way?

**Note: Edited to fix a typo in the code, which prevented me from discovering the answer (which I've added below). Keeping this question here in case others might have same question**

Answer (score 1):

I'll be honest, I skimmed what you wrote because I hope (fingers crossed) that the easy answer is `df.to_clipboard()`. This will copy the dataframe. You can pair it with `df = pd.read_clipboard()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an exception when I try to use this: ```PyperclipException: 
    Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.
    For more information, please visit
    https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#not-implemented-error
    ```

Comment: It looks like they mis-typed the url for their own error message, you can find the actual details here https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#not-implemented-error. Are you on Linux? They say that is the only place there should be an error, and they have other modules to install via pip that should fix it. I've found the `to_clipboard()` and `read_clipboard()` super useful, so I think they are worth having even if they don't fix this exact problem (but hopefully they will!)

Answer (score 1):

I had a typo in my original code, which obscured the fact that `to_json(orient='table')` works:

```py
ser_de_df = pd.read_json(df.to_json(orient='table'), orient='table')
```

This preserves both the index labels and the names.

For a Python object that is concise, you can do this:

```py
import json

obj = json.loads(df.to_json(orient='table'))
```

If you print or repr `obj`, you'll get:

```
{'schema': {'fields': [{'name': 'baz', 'type': 'string'},
   {'name': 'qux', 'type': 'string'},
   {'name': 'foo', 'type': 'integer'},
   {'name': 'bar', 'type': 'string'}],
  'primaryKey': ['baz', 'qux'],
  'pandas_version': '0.20.0'},
 'data': [{'baz': 'd', 'qux': 'z', 'foo': 1, 'bar': 'a'},
  {'baz': 'e', 'qux': 'y', 'foo': 2, 'bar': 'b'},
  {'baz': 'f', 'qux': 'x', 'foo': 3, 'bar': 'c'}]}
```

This can then be copied and pasted, and then made back into a dataframe using:

```py
pd.read_json(json.dumps({'schema': {'fields': [{'name': 'baz', 'type': 'string'},
   {'name': 'qux', 'type': 'string'},
   {'name': 'foo', 'type': 'integer'},
   {'name': 'bar', 'type': 'string'}],
  'primaryKey': ['baz', 'qux'],
  'pandas_version': '0.20.0'},
 'data': [{'baz': 'd', 'qux': 'z', 'foo': 1, 'bar': 'a'},
  {'baz': 'e', 'qux': 'y', 'foo': 2, 'bar': 'b'},
  {'baz': 'f', 'qux': 'x', 'foo': 3, 'bar': 'c'}]}
), orient='table')
```

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work with multi-index columns, though :(

Answer (score 0):

Losing the index name seems a minor drawback in comparison to the convenience provided by `to_dict()`, and knowing that if the index name is important, all you need is a second copy pasta :

```
df.to_dict() # copy the output

new_df = pd.DataFrame(…) # paste the output, no need for from_dict
new_df.index.name = … # copy and paste the index name
```